# What does $tab1["blabla"]= mean?

Tags: php, syntax

What does the syntax $tab1["sumn inside"] mean? I couldn't find any explanation and have no idea on how to manipulate the data in here, I'm still new to php.

```
$tab1["ID_Client"] = 42421337;
$tab1["Date"] = new DateTime(’2006-06-06’);
$tab1["ID_Facture"] = 456789;
$tab1["Montant"] = 200;
$data[] = $tab1;
$tab1["ID_Client"] = 36153615;
$tab1["Date"] = new DateTime(’2018-05-30’);
$tab1["ID_Facture"] = 123456;
$tab1["Montant"] = 123;
$data[] = $tab1;
```

Comment: It is defining values for indexes of the `$tab1` array. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php is a good place to read more

Answer (score 1):

Below commented code:

```
<?php
$tab1 = []; // create ampty array $tab1

// add to $tab1 record with key "ID_Client" and value 42421337
$tab1["ID_Client"] = 42421337;

// add to $tab1 record with key "Date" and value new DateTime(’2006-06-06’)
$tab1["Date"] = new DateTime('2006-06-06');

// add to $tab1 record with key "ID_Facture" and value 456789
$tab1["ID_Facture"] = 456789;

// add to $tab1 record with key "Montant" and value 200
$tab1["Montant"] = 200;

// check $tab1 value
var_export($tab1);

// add to array $data new record with next incremental id and value $tab1
$data[] = $tab1;

//check $data value
var_export($data);
```

Here I [share PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=78b4cd9ce25d3d99425f6c7a9b1cafdd&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)